# Is it possible to access the Windows Mobile device directory structure from a DOS prompt?

Tags: windows-mobile, dos

I want to access the directory structure on a Windows Mobile device from a DOS prompt so I can automated the deletion of certain directories and files on the mobile device.

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am thinking you might have a better chance at Superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Microsoft's Power Toys:

http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=74473FD6-1DCC-47AA-AB28-6A2B006EDFE9&displaylang=en